# Can you glue graphs sharing 2 edges together like graphs sharing 1 edge?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm working on a problem to find the chromatic polynomial $\chi_\Gamma(k)$ of this graph $\Gamma$:

[image]

I know how to glue together graphs sharing 1 edge and I'm hoping I can do the same with graphs sharing 2 edges to get the following:
\begin{align}
\chi_\Gamma(k)
& = \chi_{ABDCA}(k) \cdot \frac{\chi_{BDEB}(k)}{k(k-1)} \cdot \frac{\chi_{CDFC}(k)}{k(k-1)} \cdot \frac{\chi_{DEFD}(k)}{k(k-1)(k-2)} \\[1em]
& = \chi_{C_4}(k) \cdot \frac{\chi_{C_3}(k)}{k(k-1)} \cdot \frac{\chi_{C_3}(k)}{k(k-1)} \cdot \frac{\chi_{C_3}(k)}{k(k-1)(k-2)} \\[1em]
& = k(k-1)(k^2-3k+3) \cdot \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{k(k-1)} \cdot \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{k(k-1)} \cdot \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{k(k-1)(k-2)} \\[1em]
& = k(k-1)(k^2-3k+3) \cdot (k-2) \cdot (k-2) \cdot 1 \\[1em]
& = k(k-1)(k-2)^2(k^2-3k+3).
\end{align}

Am I right?

---

**ETA**

I tried using deletion-contraction and got the following, which looks more complicated than the kind of final answer I'm used to seeing.

Consider $\Gamma\backslash AB$: there are $k$ choices for $D$; then $\chi_{P_4}(k-1)=(k-1)(k-2)^3$ choices for the 4-path $BEFC$; then $k-1$ choices for $A$; for a total of $k(k-1)^2(k-2)^3$.

Consider $\Gamma/AB$: there are $k$ choices for $D$; then
\begin{align}
\chi_{C_4}(k-1)
& = (k-1)(k-2)((k-1)^2-3(k-1)+3) \\
& = (k-1)(k-2)(k^2-5k+7)
\end{align}
for the 4-cycle $BEFCB=AEFCA$; for a total of $k(k-1)(k-2)(k^2-5k+7)$.

Therefore
\begin{align}
\chi_\Gamma(k)
& = \chi_{\Gamma\backslash AB}(k) - \chi_{\Gamma/AB}(k) \\
& = k(k-1)^2(k-2)^3 - k(k-1)(k-2)(k^2-5k+7) \\
& = k(k-1)(k-2)((k-1)(k-2)^2-(k^2-5k+7)) \\
& = k(k-1)(k-2)((k^3-5k^2+8k-4)-(k^2-5k+7)) \\
& = k(k-1)(k-2)(k^3-6k^2+13k-11).
\end{align}

Comment: This unfortunately does not work since it assumes that $E,D,F$ have distinct colors. However, your approach would work if the graphs share a clique. Here, you can use deletion-contraction formula, and try to do it so that you get complete graphs or chordal graphs in the process.

Comment: @caduk Isn't that assumption justified, since $EDFE\cong C_3=K_3$?

Comment: The product of the first three terms  correspond to the chromatic polynomial of $G\backslash (E,F)$. In this formula, some coloring are counted with the same colors for $E$ and $F$. (The last term is one, so you are basically saying that the chromatic polynomial of $G$ is the same as $G\backslash (E,F)$.

Comment: @caduk Do you mean $G\backslash EF$? It seems to me that the first term $\chi_{ABCD}(k)$ alone corresponds to the polynomial of $G\backslash(E,F)$.

Comment: I mean the graph $G$ with only the edge $EF$ removed, not the two nodes.